# Why am I banned from raising flags?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

I am unable to flag any post as I am banned from flagging for seven days? I have raised **48** helpful flags and had  **3** flags rejected *(2 of them were yesterday)*, I understand why the 3 of my flag raised were declined *however I have a healthy flag ratio 48:3*.

### Screenshots

---

[image: banned from flagging]
[image: three declined flag]

---

***How is it fair to ban me from raising flags? @moderators***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag ban is an automated network-wide process which the moderators have no control over, you can see the details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/132874.

In short, it doesn't look at your total flag ratio, rather it just tracks your flags raised over the last week and warns/blocks you from flagging further if a certain threshold of declined flags is reached. Since it's a rolling check, the ban should never last longer than a week, and possibly be lifted early if pending flags that haven't been processed yet would also affect the count.